# Creating an array of game objects

Tags: xna-4.0

G'day All,

If I have a number of objects called enemies on the screen, how can I put them into an array?
My initial thought was to do it at the time they were created.  I put a declaration in the top of my Game.cs file:

```
public enemy[] enemiesArray = new enemy[5];
```

Then when I create the enemies I tried to add them to the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) // This will create 2 sprites
        {
            Vector2 position = new Vector2((i+1) * 300, (i+1) * 200);
            Vector2 direction = new Vector2(10, 10);
            float velocity = 10;
            int ID = i;

            Components.Add(new skull(this, position, direction, velocity, ID));
            skullsArray[i] = skull; // This line is wrong
        }
```

I have also tried to to it in the update() method using code like this:

```
foreach (GameComponent component1 in Components)
        {
            int index = component1.ID;
            if (component1.ToString() == "enemy")
            {
                enemiesArray[index] = component1
            }
         }
```

But that falls down because component1 does not have an ID.  I have to assume that as the program enumerates through each GameComponent it can only access a limited range of data for the component.

In the end I want to be able to refer to my enemies as enemy[1], enemy[2], etc.

Thanks,
Andrew.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you cant use a List which works a lot like an array, but it has a variable length. Then you could do this:

```
List<Enemy> EnemyList;

//You have to initalize it somewhere in Initalize or LoadContent (or the constructor)
```

You can add enemies just like you would add components (because Components is a `List<GameComponent>`

```
EnemyList.Add(enemy);
```

Then you can access the enemy:

```
EnemyList[index].DoSomething();
```

EDIT: just looked at your code again and I noticed that skull doesn't exist. Did you mean

```
new skull(this, position, direction, velocity, ID);
```

Because otherwise you are trying to add a class to the array rather than an instance of the class :)

Answer (score 2):

assuming you have put the line `public enemy[] enemiesArray = new enemy[5];`
 inside your game class then your enemiesArray is just a field of your Game class not a game component, you should be able to reference it as

```
myGameClass.enemiesArray[1]
```

Assuming that your game class is in scope.

also as @annonymously says lists are easier to resize at runtime than arrays so consider using 'List(5) enemiesArray;' instead

this is not a very scaleable way of handling it however so i suggest you research how to create and register GameComponents.  also consider making it generic so you can have one place to reference all your game items instead of having enemiesArray, bulletsArray, someOtherArray, etc

an easy way is to have an abstract class like

```
public abstract class GameThing
{
     public Vector2 Position {get; set;}
     //some other props...
}
```

and then use this as a base for your game items so Enemy is defined as

```
public class Enemy : GameThing
{
    //some props
}
```

and instead of 
`public enemy[] enemiesArray = new enemy[5];` 
you would use 
`public GameThing[] gameItemsArray= new GameThing[5];`
an add items like so

```
gameItemsArray[1] = new Enemy();
```

Comment: That's a great next step and I plan to try that inheritance process.  Ta.

Comment: you should do it sooner rather than later, can be a pig to retrofit this stuff, good luck with the game though :)